# How to zero out cart total IF a custom checkout field has a value in it?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Checkout Field plugin to add a custom field to the checkout process. If someone types in a value into the that field I would like to zero out the cart total. This is not a coupon. I did not want the user to type a value then type a coupon code.

So, if the field is not blank I want the cart total to be 0.

Ideas?

Comment: Which checkout plugin do you use ?

Comment: Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce by By ThemeHiGH

Comment: The ThemeHigh have 2 plugins to customize WooCommerce checkout fields. If you are using the free plugin, you can ask questions on their wordPress.org support forum (https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/). If you are using the premium plugin, you can ask support in the premium plugin support (https://themehigh.freshdesk.com/support/solutions).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the premium **Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce** plugin then you have the required option within the plugin.

As said in the documentation,

- Select and edit the custom field which should change the cart total, from the plugin settings.
- Set **price** as **-100** and **price type** as **Percentage of Cart Contents Total**.

That's it. You will see that, the cart total is being deducted when some value is typed into that field.

If you need further help please contact the ThemeHigh support from the links given in comment section of your question.